# Double check Inclusive OR Statements

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

Well I just made a question asking how to simply
`~(i + -1) < -1` which turned out to be `i > 1`

Making a `JAVA` deobfuscator and here is what I have so far.. I just want people to tell me which ones I did wrong? if any just double checking.

`~i > -1`  is `i < 0`

`~i < -1` is `i > 0`

`~i > ~classA.var` is `i < classA.var`

`~i >= ~j` is `i <= j`

`~i <= ~b` is `i >= b`

`~i == -1` is `i == 0`

`~classA.var < -1` is `classA.var > 0`

`~classA.var > -1` is `classA.var < 0`

`~classA.var == ~classB.var` is `classA.var == classB.var`

`~(-1 + i) < -1` is `i > 1`

`~(i + -1) < -1` is `i > 1`

`~(i & 0x22) != -1` is `(i & 0x22) == 0`        <- seems `wrong`..

Seems the correct answer by **Eng.Fouad** is

`~(i & 0x22) != -1` is `(i & 0x22) != 0`        <- correct so far.

These are all the patterns my deobfuscator supports so far.. probably will find a bunch more.

(Any wrong ones?) I Fear the ones with `==` signs may be wrong.. i've tested them and they seem to work..

Thanks I appreciate the support, i'm a beginner to programming only programmed half a year and math isn't my strong point.

Comment: `~i` is `-i - 1`, so yes `~i == -1` is quivalent to `i == 0`

Comment: But `~(i) != -1` is `(i) == 0)` so whys that lol (maybe thats wrong i dont know, i winged it)

Comment: Just try `System.out.println(~(0))` and you will find it's really `-1`

Comment: yup I don't even need to use `System.out.println` not even compile anything hehe `DrJava`'s Interactions console.  But I still don't feel right with that `!=` to `==` one

Comment: You're stil having problems with terminology `~` is **not** "inclusive OR" - it's a bitwise complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace each `~x` with `-x - 1`:

- `~i > -1` **==>** `-i - 1 > -1` **==>** `-i > 0` **==>** `i < 0`
- `~i < -1` **==>** `-i - 1 < -1` **==>** `-i < 0` **==>** `i > 0`

and so on.

Comment: Yeah thats what that guy told me in the other question.. just replace the signs to everything.. seems `==`'s stays the same out of any other signs only value decrements by 1 if negative and increment by 1 if positive if negative and increments by 1 if positive (and add `- sign`)..  but `!=`  turns to `==` really makes me almost explode

Comment: Ah you see `~(i & 0x22) != -1` is `(i & 0x22) == 0`  I do believe is wrong now.. because  `(0 & 0x22) == 0` = `true`   yet `~(0 & 0x22) != -1` = `false` they ain't right.

Comment: @SSpoke Why did you replace `==` with `!=`? `~(0 & 0x22) == 0` is equivalent to `-(0 & 0x22) - 1 == 0` and you cannot move `-1` to the other side because of the equivalence `==`

Comment: Err.. it's obfuscated java code which I decompiled.. it comes with it being `!=` already I'm trying to write a tool here to clean it up. So I'd like to either keep it `!=` (if thats the best I can do) or else make it `==` (nicer) but has to work the same.. in sense I want to remove all `~` signs.. when I look at java source with them I really screw up. I'm writing my deobfuscation patterns in java bytecode which is hard as it is. Not as hard as finding the clean answer :P

Comment: You cannot convert `!=` to `==`

Comment: So how will it look? `~(i & 0x22) != -1`  to `(i & 0x22) != 0` ya? that seems way to easy to be true.. :| it just seems that it modifies everything in `(` to `)` with opposite value.. so the answer changes too.. I don't really have access to obfuscation tool myself.. so I cannot write test examples and see what they look like obfuscated so it's all guess work for me.. but I think.. it may look something like this `(anIntArray & 0x22) == 0` (look at some old source code of something very similar)

Comment: @SSpoke You are right `~(i & 0x22) != -1` is equivalent to `(i & 0x22) != 0` :)

Comment: Haha wait up there.. I wish I was.. and it does seem something like that.. but either this is lying to me.. or.. maybe i'm not using this right.. or maybe it's not as right as you think I am lol check this image.. http://i.imgur.com/L2PGx.png

Comment: @SSpoke You again convert `==` to `!=` :P

Comment: Haha dammit! now it works!, Guess i'll close this question.. until I have more questions lol